# PHP preg_replace error: Unknown modifier ']'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Apologies for yet another preg_replace question!

I'm getting the error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg.php on line 6
```

When running the following preg_replace:

```
$newContent = preg_replace('<img [^>]*.gif[^>]*?>','MATCHED',$newContent);
```

I've run the regex through a couple of online regex builders and it seems sound. Any ideas what I'm missing here? Am I using `]` incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a delimiter around your expression:

```
$newContent = preg_replace('|<img [^>]*.gif[^>]*?>|','MATCHED',$newContent);
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked a treat. Thanks very much Benjamin.